# How to make this code simplier?

Tags: java

I would like to ask some tips on how to make this code simplier

```
    private void outputPatternList(String message) throws IOException {

    try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(patternList, true))) {
        out.write(message);
        out.write("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're only performing two writes here. You can't know whether this is the last write or not. Does the caller know? Perhaps you should check whether the file already exists and write a `\n` as a *prefix* (if it already exists) instead of as a suffix?

Comment: "Perhaps you should check whether the file already exists and write a \n as a prefix (if it already exists) instead of as a suffix?"
I think this one is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code to this:

```
private void outputPatternList(List<String> lines) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder  = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line : lines) {
         builder.append(line).append("/n");
    }
    String message = builder.toString().trim();
    try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(patternList, true))) {
        out.write(message);
    }
}
```